# How to print findBySql yii2

Tags: yii2, find-by-sql

im using findBySql in yii2, i need to print the count of the query, but i only got the 'cidade' index.

Query :

```
$a2m = AlarmesCorrentes::findBySql('SELECT COUNT(CIDADE) AS CONTA, CIDADE 
from 
alarmes_correntes WHERE  lastUpdate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
GROUP  BY 
CIDADE ORDER BY CONTA DESC LIMIT 7 ')->all();
```

Printing :

```
  foreach($a2m as $m ){

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($m['CIDADE']);
   // print_r($m['CONTA']);
    echo "</pre>";
  }

?>
```

Getting unknown property: app\modulos\dashboard_intragov\models\AlarmesCorrentes::CONTA

My DB data in View Format:

[image: My DB data in view format]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest way is 
in your model AlarmesCorrentes

add  a public var with the same name of the alias  you are using eg: $conta

```
class AlarmesCorrentes extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public $conta;
   .......
```

Comment: OMG, Thx  :D  Jah Bless

Comment: i'm sorry but what mean  "D Jah Bless" ?

Comment: Jah Bless  , "God Bless You" "Jah Bless You" , mean God in Rastafarianism  and :D = emoticon haha